# What kind of paint/stain will prevent bees?

Tags: pest-control, pest

For exposed pine, like a roof eave, how can the wood be treated to
prevent bees from tunneling into the wood, or building nests?

Edit: Currently, I'm using a water-based stain, to no effect.

Comment: Bees do not tunnel into wood. Nor do they build nests. I think you might be worried about wasps, which are realy different creatures.

Comment: Kate, yes, with the exception of: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carpenter_bee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paint it or seal it and add Bug Juice to to the paint/stain/sealer. You can read about bug juice [here](http://www.weatherall.com/1053BugJuice.html).

Comment: I'd rather not use a pesticide, is there something else that would act as a deterrent?